# REGEX: match text which containts phrases and it is included between two words

Tags: regex

I have to match the text which contains some phrases and it must be included between two constants. Let me give an example: 
My upper and lower limit are the same e.g. "START". Now there are more blocks of text which are limit by "START". I want to capure the text between the limits but the captured text must contain some phrases.

```
START
text1 text1 text1 phrase1 text text
START
text2 text2 phrase2 text2
START
text3 phrase1
START
```

Now I want to capture text with phrase1. It is "text1 text1 text1 phrase1 text text" and "text3 phrase1".

Matched text might include START word.

My attempt (does not work in the proper way) is: `START((.|\s)*?phrase1(.|\s)*?)START`.

When `START text1 text1 text1 phrase1 text text START` is caught I save it to variable and I use replace regex method with "START", so after it it looks like this:

```
START
text2 text2 phrase2 text2
START
text3 phrase1
START
```

After the second loop I got:

```
START
text2 text2 phrase2 text2
START
```

And when I got 3rd loop (if it works regex should return false) but I it crashes. In some online regex it shows no match so it sth wrong with the pattern.

Edit: Code for the looping added

```
set regEx = new RegEx
//sInputString is my text

regEx.pattern = "START((.|\s)*?phrase1(.|\s)*?)START"
set matches = regEx.Execute(sInputString)

do while (matches.count <> 0)
    sInputString = regEx.Replace(sInputString, "START")
    set matches = regEx.Execute(sInputString) //this line crashes after "ending loop"
    //saving to array
loop
```

Comment: Any particular language?

Comment: please post your code. I have a feeling it has something to do with how you handle when there are no matches

Comment: It is used in VBA. It uses VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 library. I have added the code. Do you think (despise efficiency and so on) the pattern should work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `(.|\s)*?` construct is very inefficient and causes lots of pain to regex users. Always replace it with `.*?` (with singleline modifier), or `[\s\S]*?` or with an unroll-the-loop'ed regex.

In your case, you can use an unroll-the-loop regex like this:

```
\bSTART\b([^S]*(?:S(?!TART\b)[^S]*)*)
```

It matches:

- `\bSTART\b` - a whole word `START` (you may omit `\b` if you are not using whole words)
- `([^S]*(?:S(?!TART\b))*)` - a capturing group matching

  - `[^S]*` - 0 or more characters other than `S`
  - `(?:S(?!TART\b)[^S]*)*` - 0 or more sequences of...

    - `S(?!TART\b)` - `S` not followed with `TART` and a word boundary
    - `[^S]*` - 0 or more characters other than `S`

To get

```
text1 text1 text1 phrase1 text text
text2 text2 phrase2 text2
text3 phrase1
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mS8wH9/3)

Now, if you only need the 2 substrings, just add `\bSTART\b` at the end and it will consume the trailing `START`:

```
\bSTART\b([^S]*(?:S(?!TART\b)[^S]*)*)\bSTART\b
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/mS8wH9/4) (captures `text1 text1 text1 phrase1 text text` and `text3 phrase1`).

This second regex is essentially the same as `(?s)\bSTART\b(.*?)\bSTART\b`, but is much more efficient when it comes to longer texts, but the `.*?` lazy dot matching (*matches 0 or more any characters but as few as possible to return a valid match*) is preferable when the substrings are short.

And the last note: you do not  have to use word boundary `\b` if you do not need to match a whole word.

Comment: Fixed one bug, forgot `[^S]*`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I will come back to this tomorrow because I cant tell you right now if it works for my purpose - it's a little more complicated than I 've shown - and because I'm totally new to regex I cannot say just by looking at it. I've manipulated some texts and patterns on regex demo and it seems to be ok for my task.